# Creating a new column/variable in R based on conditions of other columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset (called df) with ~1000 rows and 30 variables, and I'm trying to create a new column 'type'.
This variable would have different values based on the values of 3 other columns, 'opened', 'closed', and 'received'.

```
If received is populated, then type = group_1. (received does not = NA)
If received is blank, but closed = yes, then type = group_2.
If opened = AC then type = group_3.
```

Is there a way to do this? I'm struggling a bit.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a combination of `mutate` and `case_when` function from the `dplyr` package. Here’s a simple way to do it for your specific needs.

First, install and load the `dplyr` package: `install.packages("dplyr"); library(dplyr)`; then do:

```
df <- df %>%
      mutate(type = case_when(
        !is.na(received) ~ "group_1",           # If 'received' is not empty, then 'type' is 'group_1'
        is.na(received) & closed == "yes" ~ "group_2",   # If 'received' is empty and 'closed' is 'yes', then 'type' is 'group_2'
        opened == "AC" ~ "group_3",            # If 'opened' is 'AC', then 'type' is 'group_3'
        TRUE ~ NA_character_                   # For any other case, 'type' will be NA (you can change this as needed)
      ))
```

Comment: The second condition `is.na(received)` is not needed, as it is guaranteed by the first case not being true.

Comment: Do you know what short-circuiting is?

Comment: I included is.na(received) explicitly in the second condition to make the logic particularly clear, especially for those who might be new to using case_when or conditional logic in R. It's intended to illustrate the applied logic.

Comment: Yes, I know it. Thank you for your input. The operation would be faster w/o the is.na() and short circuiting. Nevertheless it's easier to understand for @user17753 since it matches his question

Answer (score 1):

Using `case_when()` from `dplyr` we can try:

```r
library(dplyr)

df$type <- case_when(
    df$received != ""  ~ "group_1",
    df$closed == "yes" ~ "group_2",
    df$open == "AC"    ~ "group_3"
)
```

This answer assumes that by `received` being "populated" it means that it is not empty string.  If instead/additionally you need to consider `NA` values, then we can add an `is.na()` check.